# Weather widget in your app?

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, weather

So I'm working on an app and I'd like it to have a Weather Widget inside of one of my Linear Layouts. It this possible?
I have searched the web and didn't find any useful answer for my question. So please help! If you know how, post some code or something. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this tutorial. This is easy to use: [link](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/05/build-weather-app-json-http-android.html?m=1)

Comment: This only provides a tutorial on how to create a weather app - not *add* a weather *widget* to an app.